# Scrapy CrawlSpider processing Javascript function-based links

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to solve what seems to be a rare problem. The pages I want to scrape are all easily downloadable, but the links to each page is managed by a javascript function. If I can get away with not using splash or selenium, I'd rather not, considering the links should be easily buildable. The links all have the form of

```
<a href="javascript:fn_egov_view('2106022');" title="This is the title.">This is the title.
```

Which produce a link of the form:

```
https://ombudsman.abc.de/eng/rli/lgs/na.do?mode=view&blNo=2106022
```

So, they would seem to be easily traversable by extracting the number from the link and then appending it to the base url, which never changes.

My code for doing this looks like

```
class MyCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ombudsman'
    allowed_domains = ['ombudsman.abc.de']
    start_urls = ['https://ombudsman.abc.de/eng/rli/lgs/na.do?mode=list']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="legSchVO"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a'), follow=True, callback='parse_item', process_links='process_links'),
    )

    def process_links(self, links):
        for link in links:
            url_number = re.findall(r'\d+', link.url)
            link.url = "https://ombudsman.abc.de/eng/rli/lgs/na.do?mode=view&blNo=" + url_number
            yield links

    def parse_item(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=ReleasesItem(), response=response)
        l.default_output_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip(), replace_escape_chars)

        l.add_value('rel_org', 'Ombudsman')
        l.add_xpath('rel_title', '//*[@id="container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/dl[1]/dd/text()')
        l.add_xpath('rel_summary', '//*[@id="container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td')
        l.add_xpath('rel_scraped_date', '//*[@id="container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/dl[3]/dd[1]/text()')
        l.add_value('rel_url', response.url)
        yield l.load_item()
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the `LinkExtractor` in the Rule, is not picking up the `href=""` portion of the link at all, and therefore just sending an empty list to `process_links`. The crawler then stops after returning only the first page.

Any way to get `LinkExtractor` to return the href as the url as is? Or if not, any recommendations about how to do this?

Comment: maybe first check what it get in `href` or in all `HTML`. Maybe it gives you different HTML/href when you it without JavaScript.

Comment: No difference with javascript disabled. The links just don't function at all.

Comment: I think I see mistake - you use `yield links` but it may need `yield link.url`. You could add `print()` in functions to see what you have in variables.

Comment: I have tried print functions. process_links receives an empty list.

Comment: and did you use `print()` to check other values in function? Maybe this way you will see why it sends empty list. It is called "print debuging".

Answer (score 0):

`url_number = re.findall(r'\d+', link.url)` return list, so use `url_number[0]` instead of `url_number`, and `yield link` instead of `yield links`

like:

```
    def process_links(self, links):
        for link in links:
            url_number = re.findall(r'\d+', link.url)
            if len(url_number)>0: 
                link.url = "https://ombudsman.abc.de/eng/rli/lgs/na.do?mode=view&blNo=" + url_number[0]
            yield link
```

Comment: Thanks for the fixes. I had tried different things there. I can't tell if it works yet, because it seems nothing is being passed into process_links except an empty list.

Comment: have you verified xpaths?

Comment: Yeah, I think the LinkExtractor does some sort of pre-processing to determine what is a link and what isn't that is stopping it from accepting `href="javascript:fn_egov_view('2106022');"` type links as acceptable. It is finding no links, so it is passing nothing.